# asynchronous Inter thread communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, boost, signals

I'm making a cross plateform program that embbed a small RARP server (implemented with winpcap/pcap) and runs 2 TCP IP servers. I have to use C++.

So i will have at least 4 threads, the main one wich countain the controller, 2 TCP/IP async socket, and the RARP server.

I planned to use c++ BOOST Asio and Thread, because i need to run this program in both linux and windows XP. (and i can't use Qt)

I would perform asynchronous Inter thread communication.

For exemple fire events inside a loop without blocking the loop

How can i do that? With a portable librairy preferably.

Thank you

Comment: I think you'll have better luck getting an answer if you ask a more narrow version of this question.  You have several questions in here, some not related to others.... It's very scattered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no generic solution to this, you can't just interrupt a thread and deliver a notification to be processed.  That causes horrible re-entrancy problems and large servings of deadlock.  A notification can only be processed when the thread is in a quiescent state.

An operating system usually has services available that make it possible.  In Windows this is typically done by posting a message to the message queue.  Read by the message loop, which is the 'idle' state for a UI thread.  Or by leveraging asynchronous procedure calls, fired when the thread is blocking and explicitly allowed APCs to run.

But you cut this off by requiring a non-platform specific solution.  In which case you're pretty much doomed to re-invent an OS feature.  You'll need a thread-safe queue that you poll in the thread that needs to receive the notification.  A message queue, read by a message loop.

Comment: Because i already use boost asio, im using boost asio io_service object to make async function calls. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ICE messaging](http://www.zeroc.com/ice.html)

It supports syncrhonous and asyncrounous messaging between processes whether they are on the same node or not.

There are bindings for C++, Obj-C, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, and PHP.